# printk second output

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, printk

When I printk(KERN_INFO, ...), I get something like this:

<6>[116584.000183] ...

What is the number between the square brackets exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a timestamp with microsecond resolution. See the [`printk` source](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/kernel/printk.c#L796).

Answer (score 4):

Seconds since startup. You can control whether this is shown with the `CONFIG_PRINTK_TIME` variable in kernel config.